# Carrierwave is not working with devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I am new in ruby on rails. I am trying to update the user avatar using devise and carrierwave. I have integrated carrierwave on another controller and it is working fine there,But I don't know why it is not working with devise.

I am using this tutorial

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-use-carrierwave-with-devise

No error is showing on the form and logs are not showing any information either. 
I have checked the logs and in the update query there is no data about the avatar,while when I print the post data parameters they contain the multipart data.

This is the code

Logs

```
Started PUT "/users" for 10.0.2.2 at 2018-01-22 17:22:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GbwVhRNMIJMnXIxF/v39fIWBSCOVN9/XEVXq9Tar+H0F0vq9JMDE8aM9efSqFCjr2WKaegsd2XhoLR5TyUyl8Q==", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc1a3288f40 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20180122-13485-1fn61vx.png>, @original_filename="Screen Shot 2018-01-18 at 8.28.55 PM.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2018-01-18 at 8.28.55 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "avatar_cache"=>"", "user"=>{"admin"=>"true", "email"=>"admin@test.com", "first_name"=>"donation", "last_name"=>"simple", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 450215437], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 450215437], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "users" SET "first_name" = $1, "last_name" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4[0m  [["first_name", "donation"], ["last_name", "simple"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-22 17:22:39.206951"], ["id", 450215437]]
  [1m[35m (4.3ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:8090/admins
Completed 302 Found in 216ms (ActiveRecord: 6.4ms)


Started GET "/admins" for 10.0.2.2 at 2018-01-22 17:22:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by AdminsController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 450215437], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users"."admin_type" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 450215437], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users"."id", "users"."first_name", "users"."last_name", "users"."admin_type" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 450215437], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT SUM("donations"."amount_cents") FROM "donations"[0m
  [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT SUM("donations"."amount_cents") FROM "donations" WHERE "donations"."payment_type" = $1[0m  [["payment_type", 2]]
  [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT SUM("donations"."amount_cents") FROM "donations" WHERE "donations"."payment_type" = $1[0m  [["payment_type", 0]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: uniq is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1 (use distinct instead) (called from index at /vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:68)
  [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT DISTINCT "donations"."user_id" FROM "donations"[0m
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users"."admin_type" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 450215437], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users"."id", "users"."first_name", "users"."last_name", "users"."admin_type" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 450215437], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT SUM("donations"."amount_cents") FROM "donations"[0m
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT SUM("donations"."amount_cents") FROM "donations" WHERE "donations"."payment_type" = $1[0m  [["payment_type", 2]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT SUM("donations"."amount_cents") FROM "donations" WHERE "donations"."payment_type" = $1[0m  [["payment_type", 0]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: uniq is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1 (use distinct instead) (called from index at /vagrant/donation-simple/app/controllers/admins_controller.rb:68)
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT DISTINCT "donations"."user_id" FROM "donations"[0m
  Rendering admins/index.html.erb within layouts/admin
  [1m[36mOrganization Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT id, name, url FROM "organizations"[0m
  Rendered admins/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (2.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (13.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_sidebar.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 546ms (Views: 505.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)


Started GET "/img/icon-color.png" for 10.0.2.2 at 2018-01-22 17:22:40 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
```

---

view file

```
        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- BEGIN PROFILE SIDEBAR -->
        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {:method => :put, :multipart => true}) do |f| %>

            <% if resource.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2><%= pluralize(resource.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this pet from being saved:</h2>

              <ul>
              <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
              <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <% end %>                    

        <div class="profile-sidebar">
            <!-- PORTLET MAIN -->
            <div class="portlet light profile-sidebar-portlet ">
                <!-- SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
                <div class="profile-userpic lg-img text-center">
                    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                        <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt=""> </div>
                        <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; height: 150px;"> </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="btn default btn-file">
                                <span class="fileinput-new"> Select image </span>
                                <span class="fileinput-exists"> Change </span>
                                <input type="file" name="avatar"> </span>
                                <input type="hidden" name="avatar_cache">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"> Remove </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
                <!-- SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
                <div class="profile-usertitle">
                    <div class="profile-usertitle-name">  </div>
                    <div class="profile-usertitle-job"> Developer </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
                <!-- SIDEBAR BUTTONS -->
                <div class="profile-userbuttons">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle green btn-sm">Follow</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-circle red btn-sm">Message</button>
                </div>
                <!-- END SIDEBAR BUTTONS -->
                <!-- SIDEBAR MENU -->
                <div class="profile-usermenu">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="page_user_profile_1.html">
                                <i class="icon-home"></i> Overview </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="page_user_profile_1_account.html">
                                <i class="icon-settings"></i> Account Settings </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="page_user_profile_1_help.html">
                                <i class="icon-info"></i> Help </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- END MENU -->
            </div>
            <!-- END PORTLET MAIN -->
            <!-- PORTLET MAIN -->
            <div class="portlet light ">
                <div>
                    <h4 class="profile-desc-title">About Marcus Doe</h4>
                    <span class="profile-desc-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet diam nonummy nibh dolore. </span>
                    <div class="margin-top-20 profile-desc-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                        <a href="http://www.keenthemes.com">www.keenthemes.com</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="margin-top-20 profile-desc-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/keenthemes/">@keenthemes</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="margin-top-20 profile-desc-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/keenthemes/">keenthemes</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PORTLET MAIN -->
        </div>
        <!-- END BEGIN PROFILE SIDEBAR -->
        <!-- BEGIN PROFILE CONTENT -->
        <div class="profile-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="portlet light ">
                        <div class="portlet-title tabbable-line">
                            <div class="caption caption-md">
                                <i class="icon-globe theme-font hide"></i>
                                <span class="caption-subject font-blue-madison bold uppercase">Profile Account</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <!-- PERSONAL INFO TAB -->
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1_1">
                                      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
                                      <%= f.hidden_field :admin, value: true %>

                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <%= f.label :email,class:'control-label' %><br />
                                        <%= f.email_field :email,class:'form-control',placeholder: 'Email', autofocus: true %>
                                      </div>

                                      <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
                                        <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
                                      <% end %>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <%= f.label :first_name,class:'control-label' %><br />
                                          <%= f.text_field :first_name,class:'form-control',placeholder: 'First name', required: false %>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <%= f.label :last_name,class:'control-label' %><br />
                                          <%= f.text_field :last_name,class:'form-control',placeholder: 'Last name', required: false %>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <%= f.label :password,class:'control-label' %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
                                          <%= f.password_field :password,class:'form-control',placeholder: 'Password', autocomplete: "off" %>
                                          <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                                            <br />
                                            <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
                                          <% end %>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <%= f.label :password_confirmation,class:'control-label' %><br />
                                          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,class:'form-control',placeholder: 'Confirm Password', autocomplete: "off" %>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <%= f.label :current_password,class:'control-label' %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
                                          <%= f.password_field :current_password,class:'form-control',placeholder: 'Current Password',autocomplete: "off" %>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="actions">
                                          <%= f.submit "Update",:class => 'btn green' %>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                      <% end %>
                                      <h3>Cancel my account</h3>
                                        <p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>
                                        <%= link_to "Back", :back,:class => 'btn blue' %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PROFILE CONTENT -->
    </div>
</div>
```

---

avatar_uploader

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_whitelist
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

---

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  add_flash_types :success, :warning, :danger, :info
  protect_from_forgery prepend: true
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  layout :layout_by_resource

  helper_method :current_user

  def logged_in_using_omniauth
    session[:logged_in_using_omniauth].present?
  end
  helper_method :logged_in_using_omniauth

  private

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "admin"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end


  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if(current_user.admin)
      '/admins'
    else
      '/donations/donor_history'
    end
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    '/users/sign_in' #your path
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:admin, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:first_name,:last_name,:avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:admin, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,:current_password,:first_name,:last_name,:avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar)
    end
  end

end
```

I am trying from 3 days but still no success. Please help me in this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to add a comment but can't? Anyway have you mounted the uploader to the user model?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to change your user model from this...

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :remember_me, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar

  validates_presence_of   :avatar
  validates_integrity_of  :avatar
  validates_processing_of :avatar
end
```

to this...

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :remember_me, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar

  validates_presence_of   :avatar
  validates_integrity_of  :avatar
  validates_processing_of :avatar
end
```